# Elasticsearch - create many fields in index

Tags: elasticsearch

I check my elasticsearch index because I head error "Fields limit exceeded".
And I noticed elastic search create a new field in mapping always if nested filed has different name.

My document example:

```json
    "level": "Low",
    "updated_at": "2022-05-22 13:19:12",
    "distribution": {
                "single": {
                    "1102": {
                        "groups": "Medium",
                        "groups_level_ids": [
                            null
                        ],
                        "company": "Inter Cop",
                    }
                },
                "multiple_groups": [],
                "all_levels": []
            },
```

So the problem is with field **distribution** and nested field **single.1102**.
That number (1102) is different in every document.

But why elastic treat all this field **distribution.single.1102** as a new first level field if first level field is always **distribution**?

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch flattens the JSON, hence `distribution.single.1102` is created as a new field, you can refer how [array of objects flattened](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-arrays-flattening-objects) and from same link. [image]

**Due to flattening reason, and you have a variable key field you are exhausting the field limit of Elasticsearch. To fix issue, you should model you data in a way that variables always comes in the value of a key field to avoid the issue.**